# Why do spheres indented by a curve follow the curve when later rolled on the same curve?

Tags: kinematics, rotational-dynamics, everyday-life

In this [Youtube Short](https://youtube.com/shorts/ok0m__oCSfs?feature=share) it was mentioned a way of constructing a shape that followings any curve one could draw. Apparently the motivation to construct it is to do the following, roll a sphere of clay as it rolls on the curve (on a paper). The identations would cause it to exactly follow the curve.

...but...why? Why does the intendations cause it to follow exactly the curve that caused it's indentations?